# RUNnning Powershell commands in Docker image fails

Tags: powershell, docker

I have this in my Dockerfile.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-nanoserver-1803 AS build
WORKDIR /src 
...
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
RUN Write-Output  'hello from ps'
```

I run docker build and get to this point in my dockerfile, then I get the error message below.

> Step 8/24 : RUN Write-Output 'hello'
>    ---> Running in ea5d79c5698c
>   container ea5d7....5cb94f67 encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
>    onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(174)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF738A6C00A: (caller: 00007FF738A3ECEA) Exception(2) tid(36c) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.

**EDITS/UPDATES**
It seems that

- microsoft/aspnetcore-build does not support .net core 2.1 (but has
  both powershell and node installed)
- microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk is meant
  for building, but missing both powershell and node
- Same goes for 
  microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-nanoserver-1803

Comment: Basically, the `nanoserver` image don't have powershell by default. You can use cmd instead, as answered by yourself bellow, or use the `servercore` as base image, or still install the powershell manually in your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use curl instead

```
RUN curl.exe -o node.zip https://nodejs.org/dist/v9.2.0/node-v9.2.0-win-x64.zip && \
  mkdir "C:\\Program Files\\node" && \
  tar.exe -xf node.zip -C "C:\\Program Files\\node" --strip-components=1
```

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2017/12/19/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/

Comment: Your link has expired. Here's an archived version https://web.archive.org/web/20180307190307/https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2017/12/19/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/